# How to check if left click is clicked in text field in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

What I am trying to do is that I have highlighted text and this highlight can't be removed with left click (for example: there is `self.text.tag_remove("match","1.0",END)`, which removes the highlight, but it will remove it immediately without even showing the highlight in the first place), so I want to remove highlight under the condition of left clicking in text widget.

Here is part of my code which I think might be helpful:

```
def Find(self):
    count=IntVar()
    s=self.text.search(self.entry.get(),'1.0',stopindex=END,count=count)
    self.text.tag_configure("match",background='yellow')
    end=f'{s}+{count.get()}c'
    self.text.tag_add("match",s,end)
```

`text` is object for text widget.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to the last line? :
`self.text.bind("<Button-1>",self.text.tag_remove("match","1.0",END))`

Comment: actually  i tried that before and it didnt work, it is the same problem above, it will remove highlight before even showing it in the first place.

Comment: @johnsilva You'll probably want to use `self.text.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event_data: self.text.tag_remove(...))`, as this passes a function as the callback, not the result of a function...

Comment: @EdWard ah yes, why i didnt think of lambda you are a life saver!
Thank you!
post your comment as an answer, so other can see the solution clearly, i will accept it.